# Install Ubuntu on Samsung series 5 ultra SSD

Tags: laptop, samsung, ssd

I was wondering if anyone had had any luck with installing ubuntu 12.04 on samsung series 5 ultra? The thing is that I want to install root on the SSD for fast boot (along with windows7)... if anyone has done this please tell me how.

Comment: I've done it with 12.10 and 13.04, but the results are horrendous. Check it out [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/261233/ultra-slow-internal-ssd-on-samsung-ultrabook-np530). [This dude](http://www.childsplay.mobi/blog/?p=83) says he's got it, but I wasn't able to duplicate his success.

Answer (score 1):

I used in ssd / ext4 jornaling

The hdd you put your /home

My disk

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   */dev/sdb1        22G   11G   11G  49% /
    none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    udev            1,9G  4,0K  1,9G   1% /dev
    tmpfs           1,9G  1,5M  1,9G   1% /tmp
    tmpfs           375M  920K  374M   1% /run
    none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
    none            1,9G  160K  1,9G   1% /run/shm
    none            100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
  **/dev/sda9       296G  180G  101G  65% /home
* SSD
** HDD
```

The number is 9 because I using dual boot.

When you will configure your disk you have to create a partition with 10MB for "Boot Bios"

tips and tricks:

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd

http://refugeeks.com/use-tlp-to-optimize-the-power-consumption-in-ubuntu/

find for samsung-tools ppa